# Приложение, позволяющее упаковать сайт в Android-приложение

Tags: android, iframe, phonegap

Сразу оговорюсь - **PhoneGap** позволяет упаковывать **голые Html-CSS-JS** странички. 
Мне нужно кое что **другое**: указываете ссылку - получаете что-то наподобие фрейма с сайтом в приложении. Точно знаю, такое есть, просто не могу отыскать ссылку. По-моему даже что-то русское в виде веб-сервиса.

В итоге должно получится что-то вроде виндового приложения с кинутым компонентом WebBrowser для Delphi, C# и других, только для андроид.

Заранее большое спасибо за ответ (:

Answer (score 2):

[www.appsgeyser.ru](http://www.appsgeyser.ru)
Нагуглил всё-таки сам (:

Comment: Отличный сервис. Есть такой же для iOS?